# Cклоняется ли фамилия Гендель

Tags: склонение-фамилий

Cклоняется ли немецкая фамилия Гендель?

Answer (score 2):

Склоняются подобные мужские фамилии, женские - нет. 
Например, пишу письмо Генделю Георгу (мужчине) или Гендель Иде (женщине).

Answer (score 1):

Мужская фамилия склоняется, женская - нет.

Мужские фамилии, имеющие основы на согласные и нулевое окончание в именительном падеже (на письме они кончаются согласной буквой, ь или й), кроме фамилий на -ых, -их, склоняются как существительные второго склонения мужского рода, т. е. имеют в творительном падеже окончание -ом, (-ем): Герценом, Левитаном, Гоголем, Врубелем, Хемингуэем, Гайдаем. Такие фамилии воспринимаются как «нерусские».

См.: [Как склонять фамилии](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/70-rubric-104)

Answer (score 0):

Родительный падеж (простонарод. употребительное в литературе) - "Генделев кафтан"

Comment: Вопрос о склонении вообще-то, а не о притяжательной форме. И не родительный это. Родительный - "Генделева кафтана"